# How to accept Class return in reflection?

Tags: java, class, reflection

take the following as an example:

```
public class Person {

private String name;
private Achievements achievements;

public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Achievements getAchievments() {
    return achievements;
}

}
```

and the achievements class:

```
public class Achievements {

public int amount() {
    ...
}

}
```

if i would be using the class regularly, i would go like :

```
Person p = new Person("John");
p.getAchievements().amount();
```

however, if i want to use the reflection API, how would i go about reaching to the amount(); step?

i know how to reach to the getAchievements();

however i'm blocked from the rest.

thanks

Comment: Post at least what you have

Comment: @talex im asking how to do i access such method, i posted an example. forget the code, this is the broad idea of how to access such an example

Comment: You told that you know how to get `getAchievements` with `amount` you need to do exactly the same

Comment: If you are "blocked from the rest" than show us what you already have.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand you might need something like this:

```
Person obj = new Person("qew");
Method methodGetAchievements = obj.getClass().getMethod("getAchievments");
Object achievements = methodGetAchievements.invoke(obj);
Method methodAmount = achievements.getClass().getMethod("amount");
int amount = (int) methodAmount.invoke(achievements);
```

Comment: thanks ill try this now, you're the only one that understood.